# Understanding the Definition of Coercive Functions

Tags: real-analysis, coercive

A function $f$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is said to be coercive if $$\lim_{\|\vec{x}\|\rightarrow \infty}f(\vec{x})=+\infty.$$
I do not understand the idea of taking the limit as the norm approaches infinity. Consider an example using the function $$f(\vec{x})=(x^4+y^4)\left(1-\frac{4xy}{x^4+y^4}\right).$$ As $\|\vec{x}\|\rightarrow\infty, \frac{4xy}{x^4+y^4}\rightarrow0.$ I do not understand this. Do we think of $\|\vec{x}\|\rightarrow\infty$ in the sense that $x\rightarrow\infty$ and $y\rightarrow\infty$? Some intuition would be most helpful.

Comment: $\| (x,y)\| \to \infty$ means $x^{2}+y^{2} \to \infty$. It is not necessary that both $|x|$ and $|y| \to \infty$. Only the distance of $(x,y)$ from the origin tends to $\infty$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I see. So if the distance of $(x,y)$ from the origin tends to $\infty$, why does $4xy/(x^4+y^4)$ tend to $0$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Why does $\|x\|\rightarrow\infty\implies x^2+y^2\rightarrow\infty$? Couldn't $\|x\|\rightarrow\infty\implies x^4+y^4\rightarrow\infty$ for a different norm (i.e. $4$-norm instead of the $2$-norm)?

Comment: All  norms on $\mathbb R^{n}$ are equivalent.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy so it is valid to say that $4xy/(x^4+y^4)\rightarrow 0$ since $\|x\|=x^4+y^4\rightarrow\infty$? Sorry for the elementaty questions; I am new to this.

Comment: Yes, it is true that $\frac {4xy} {x^{4}+y^{4}} \to 0$ as $\|(x,y)\| \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof of the fact that $\frac {4xy} {x^{4}+y^{4}} \to 0$ as ${x^{2}+y^{2}} \to \infty$:  Use the fact that $2xy \leq x^{2}+y^{2}$ and consider the cases $|x| \leq |y|$ and $|x| >|y|$. In the first case $\frac {x^{2}+y^{2}} {x^{4}+y^{4}} \leq \frac 2 {y^{2}}$. Second case is similar.

Comment: As you said, is it equally valid to let $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$ and consider $\lim_{r\rightarrow\infty}$?

Comment: @MB But then  you have to see how $\cos^{4} \theta+\sin ^{4} \theta$ behaves.

Answer (score 1):

You have to expand what what the notation $\lim\limits_{||\vec x||\to\infty}f(\vec x)=+\infty$ means: you get
$$ \forall A\in\mathbb{R}, \exists B>0 \text{ s.t. }\forall \vec x\in\mathbb{R}^n,||\vec x||>B\implies f(\vec x)>A,$$
Also, if you expand the notation $\lim\limits_{||\vec x||\to\infty}f(\vec x)=l\in\mathbb{R}$, you get
$$ \forall \varepsilon>0, \exists B>0 \text{ s.t. }\forall \vec x\in\mathbb{R}^n,||\vec x||>B\implies |f(\vec x)-l|<\varepsilon.$$